# What was the first English-speaking anime fangroup?

Tags: anime-history

When anime and manga first came over to English-speaking areas, I presume it was treated more like traditional national comics were, and that manga fans were still primarily comic fans - rather than there being a distinction like today.

What was the first public group that had an *anime/manga* fandom that was **distinct** from western comic fandom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [interviews with co-founder Fred Patten](http://otakuinabottle.blogspot.ie/2012/03/fred-patten-interview.html), the *Cartoon/Fantasy Organization* (C/FO) was the first anime/manga fanclub set up in 1977. Based in Los Angeles, the group started expanding into several spin-off groups in the 80s, including another major group in New York:

[image]

> 1980s C/FO New York meeting.

Most ways of accessing anime & manga were limited back then. You either had to know someone over in Japan, or visit one of very few Japanese bookshops. Nearly none of which having English translations.

[image]
[(src)](http://www.fanboy.com/2011/02/what-was-it-like-to-be-an-80s-anime-fan-in-nyc.html)

Whilst there may have been some small gatherings of friends before the C/FO, it was the first group to be open to the general public.

Many of the early members of the C/FO became prominent figures in the emergence of furry fandom.

Unfortunately, due to political in-fighting the splinter groups gradually ceased to exist, leaving only the original L.A. branch active. Their [current website](http://c_fo.tripod.com/) was last updated in 2013.

Even today, Los Angeles is one of the most important places in english-speaking territory for anime, hosting one of the largest conventions - [Anime Expo](http://www.anime-expo.org/)

Comment: For those interested, you can read more about this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime_and_manga_fandom)